# SQL Server : multiple WHERE NOT EXISTS clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

I have about 2600 rows in the `Load_Charges_IMPORT` query that are not being inserted into the `Load_Charges` query.

I am trying to insure that no duplicate primary key entries are added. The primary key is established in the `Load_Charges` query as compound key (Charge Description + Charged Amount). No keys are set in the `Load_Charges_IMPORT` query, and this data is being imported from an excel document.

Can you tell me if there is something wrong with my code and why I am getting a response of `0 row(s) affected` when I know there are 2600+ rows in `Load_Charges_IMPORT`.

```
INSERT INTO Load_Charges
    SELECT *
    FROM Load_Charges_IMPORT
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Load ID]
                    FROM Load_Charges
                    WHERE Load_Charges_IMPORT.[Load ID] = Load_Charges.[Load ID])
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Charge Description]
                        FROM Load_Charges
                        WHERE Load_Charges_IMPORT.[Charge Description] = Load_Charges.[Charge Description])
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Charged Amount] 
                        FROM Load_Charges
                        WHERE Load_Charges_IMPORT.[Charged Amount] = Load_Charges.[Charged Amount]);
```

Comment: At least one of your `not exists` conditions must be excluding more than you are expecting. Debug by testing each `not exists` condition singularly, and change to an `exists` condition to see which rows are matching (and therefore not being imported). Once you identify them you'll see where your duplicate logic is incorrect - we can't tell that for you.

Comment: What is an example of a row in the stage table that you would expect to get imported by your posted code, but is not getting imported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your EXISTS clause excludes all lines where any one of the conditions is TRUE, not only lines where all conditions are TRUE. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Load_Charges

SELECT *

FROM Load_Charges_IMPORT

WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Load_Charges 
    WHERE Load_Charges_IMPORT.[Load ID]=Load_Charges.[Load ID]
    AND Load_Charges_IMPORT.[Charge Description]=Load_Charges.[Charge Description]
    AND Load_Charges_IMPORT.[Charged Amount]=Load_Charges.[Charged Amount]);
```

Comment: I would refactor this to use alias' and change `NOT EXISTS (SELECT *` to `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1`

Comment: Note that this requires same row match, which the original query doesn't.

Comment: @DaveCullum - I would refactor to use aliases as well, but not everyone likes aliasing tables. Also, SELECT * and SELECT 1 in an Exists call perform the exact same function in recent versions of SQL Server. The differentiation is unnecessary.

Comment: @DaveCullum: The latter usually does not changing anything unless you consider it more readable.

Comment: @LaughingVergil: Why is nobody using `select 0` or `select 'foo'` instead of `select 1`? I prefer `select 1/0` to confuse readers :-)

Comment: HA!  Sorry, I know the execution plan is the same... It was all for readability and streamlining; reading "select all" versus "select 1" in your head, at least to me, implies the data is used downstream or elsewhere in the code.  @LaughingVergil I cannot comprehend the mind of a man who would turn their nose up at aliases! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to address the issue is to use a series of `LEFT JOIN`s, with a `WHERE` clause that excludes any matching record.

This is a shorter syntax, and avoids using a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO Load_Charges
SELECT imp.*
FROM 
    Load_Charges_IMPORT imp
    LEFT JOIN Load_Charges load1 ON load1.[Load ID] = imp.[Load ID]
    LEFT JOIN Load_Charges load2 ON load2.[Charge Description] = imp.[Charge Description]
    LEFT JOIN Load_Charges load3 ON load3.[Charged Amount]= imp.[Charged Amount]
WHERE load1.[Load ID] IS NULL AND load2.[Load ID] IS NULL AND load3.[Load ID] IS NULL
;
```

NB : this assumes that [Load ID] is a non-nullable field in the `Load_Charges` table. If not, any other non-nullable field can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You just quadrupled the columns returned by `SELECT *` :)

Comment: @DaveCullum : yes you are right, thanks for checking... Fixed